# How to get all tokens and NFTs in wallet by using solana/web3.js?

Tags: web3js, solana

I want to know how to get all tokens and NFTs in wallet.

As you can see at https://solscan.io/account/HEGfxcbHPdkpxZJyqPaGevaAkCGfuaB1mHF1cUv2bTGe#portfolio,
I want to get Tokens & NFTs list(and it's balance) by using solana/web3.

Such as:
---Account(HEGfxcbHPdkpxZJyqPaGevaAkCGfuaB1mHF1cUv2bTGe)---
Token:
H289e6NPwxtUJws7YJrQnfgi8gYgHnnDi7Ur9FVBCr9Y bozo 11329563.28
...

NFTs:
...

Answer (score 0):

The `getTokenAccountsByOwner` endpoint serves the exact information that you're looking for:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
      "HEGfxcbHPdkpxZJyqPaGevaAkCGfuaB1mHF1cUv2bTGe",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

You can learn more about it at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettokenaccountsbyowner